# Difference between booting from a CD/DVD and from a USB drive

Tags: usb-drive, boot-repair, cd-drive

The CD drive on my laptop doesn't work. So my computer couldn't read any CD inserted into it. (Also at present I don't have any external disc or anything else like that with me right now).  I have to perform a boot repair as I dual booted my Windows 8.1 system few days ago. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 along with Windows 8.1 but now I decided to remove Ubuntu so I deleted the Ubuntu partitions and now I have to do a boot repair for which I'll be needing a bootable drive. So I am thinking of using a USB stick for this purpose. Is there anything wrong with this? Will there be any problem later on?

I installed Ubuntu using one of my friend's CD drive( the installation didn't go quite well and I ran into problems like Mounting issues and some GRUB problem).

Comment: nice username! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there will be no problem, as long as your machine supports USB booting, the process is more or less the same.

**Long version:**

Before USB drives were used, software was installed through CD drives, and the BIOS had hooks for booting (El Torito, etc).

With the rise of USB, USB drives are now "hard disks" from the BIOS standpoint. This changes how they are booted, and makes them harder to boot on some machines.

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to repeat the question in the comment section but still  isn't  there any (even minor) difference between USB and CD in such a case?

Comment: Of course there is a difference, but the install procedure is more or less the same. I'm happy to explain it to you, please hold on a moment while I edit my answer.